# How to translate /en/file.php to file.php?lang=en in htaccess Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internationalization, multilingual

I'm writing multilingual website. I have several files on server like:

```
/index.php
/files.php
/funny.php
```

And would like to add language support by placing language code into URL like this:

```
http://mywebsite/en/index.php
```

would redirect to:

```
http://mywebsite/index.php?lang=en
```

And

```
http://mywebsite/en/files.php
```

would redirect to:

```
http://mywebsite/files.php?lang=en
```

I would like to put more languages for example:

```
http://mywebsite/ch-ZH/index.php
```

And I would like this to work only for files with php and php5 extension. Rest of files should be the same as they are.

So for example when i will go to address

```
http://mywebsite/ch-ZH/index.php
```

I would like my PHP to recognize that current path is

```
http://mywebsite
```

and NOT

```
http://mywebsite/ch-ZH
```

It's necessary for me because in my PHP code I relate on current path and would like them to work as they are working now.

Could you please write how to prepare htaccess file on Apache to meet this criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*) $3?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And for the *current path* problem, you have to know how relative URIs are resolved: Relative URIs are resolved *by the client* from a base URI that is the URI (*not filesystem path!*) of the current resource if not declared otherwise.

So if a document has the URI `/en/foo/bar` and the relative path `./baz` in it, the *client* resolves this to `/en/foo/baz` (as obviously the client doesn’t know about the actual filesystem path).
For having `./baz` resolved to `/baz`, you have to change the base URI which can be done with the [HTML element `BASE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.[^/]+)/(.*).php([5])?$ $2.php$3?lang=$1 [L]
```

This will only match .php and .php5 files, so the rest of your files will be unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ModRewrite, you can put symbolic links in the web folder (`ln -s . en`) and check the URL in PHP.